# Todo List using Python and Flask, can't reflect tasks on my "completed tasks page"

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have a Todo app made using Flask and Python with a sqlite backend (SQLAlchemy). I would like to know, how can I "move" tasks marked as completed on the "home page" to the "Completed tasks" page. I am new to programming and I can't seem to get my head around the logic

```py
# routes.py

from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from todo import app, db
from todo.forms import NewtaskForm
from todo.models import Task


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    tasks = Task.query.all()
    return render_template('home.html', title='home', tasks=tasks)


@app.route("/task/completed", methods=['GET'])
def Completed_tasks():
    return render_template('completed-tasks.html', title='Complete tasks')


@app.route("/task/<int:task_id>")
def task(task_id):
    task = Task.query.get_or_404(task_id)
    return render_template('task.html', title=task.title, task=task)


@app.route("/task/<int:task_id>/completed", methods=['POST'])
def task_complete(task_id):
    task = Task.query.get_or_404(task_id)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Task has been added', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('Completed_tasks'))
```

```py
# models.py

from datetime import datetime
from todo import db

class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.today().date(), nullable=False)
    date_due = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    time = db.Column(db.Time, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Task('{}', {}, {}, {})".format(self.title, self.date_posted, self.date_due, self.time)

db.create_all()
```

```
# Completed-tasks.html (not sure if you'll need this)

{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% if tasks %}
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <article class="media content-section">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="article-metadata">
                        <a class="mr-2" href="#">Posted on - {{ task.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</a>
                        <a class="mr-2" href="#">Due on - {{ task.date_due.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</a>
                        <a class="mr-2" href="#">Time:  {{ task.time.strftime('%H:%M') }}</a>
                    </div>
                    <h2><a class="article-title">{{ task.title }}</a></h2>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ task.description }}</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <h1>Completed Tasks</h1>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I need the selected task to be "moved" over from the home route to the completed_tasks route. I have tried everything, and all it does is redirect me to an empty "completed tasks page" with no tasks commited.

Comment: you are doing `db.session.commit()` in route `@app.route("/task/<int:task_id>/completed", methods=['POST'])` but you changing nothing. You should have flag/boolean value in your model like `completed` with default value `False`, change this value to `True` and then commit. Query the database and filter completed and incomplete tasks

Comment: adding a boolean value helped, however, when i query the database of my Completed Tasks, `task = Task.query.filter_by(complete=True)`, it does not pull through the commited information. thank you

Comment: did you check if your database got updated? you can use [sqlitebrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/). you will have to migrate the database or delete the old database and restart the flask app for changes to take place

Comment: i was able to update the database. i filtered my tasks on both pages using the boolean value you suggested and its a gem. will post the full code, maybe it will help others. Thank you @waynetech

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get it to work by adding a boolean value to my models. and filtering my database for both home page and completed page with the boolean value.

## models.py

```
class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.today().date())
    date_due = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    time = db.Column(db.Time)
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return "Task('{}', {})".format(self.title, self.complete)
```

and i filtered the home page and completed page according to the complete boolean

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    tasks = Task.query.filter_by(complete = False)
    return render_template('home.html', title='home', tasks=tasks)

@app.route("/task/<int:task_id>/completed", methods=['POST'])
def task_complete(task_id):
    task = Task.query.get_or_404(task_id)
    task.complete = True
    db.session.add(task)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your task has been completed', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('Completed_tasks'))
```